# How to get specific links when you click the scrolling text in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor framework.

I am having a doubt, can anyone clear me..

I have scrolling events from bottom to up. Whenever i click an event that is being scrolled, i want to open in a new tab. Every event is having a specific href.
How to do this application using the database.

I want to store all the events in database and parllely i want to add new events directly from website and store them in database and fetch the event to the scrolling area.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is a good choice for this. Have you decided how to do the UI? Will you use bootstrap or material design. Do you have a scroller in mind?

You can set up your server process to make http requests to fetch data from another web site (using RESTAPI?) and store them in the database. https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron lets you schedule regular server processing runs.

Thanks to Meteor's reactivity, the UI doesn't need to concern itself with the back end, data will simply appear, and a helper task will run every time to deal with changes to the data.